# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language Learners's [fourth moderator election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Glorfindel] [image: Eddie Kal]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5983115128340480/0).

Comment: Congratsssss you guysssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations Glorfindel. With your experience, I believe you'll make ELL a better place for learners (including myself, of course). And congratulations also to Eddie Kal! With more than 1.5k helpful flags, you'll gonna make a great moderator!

Answer (score 10):

Thanks [everyone](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent) for taking part in the election and for your support! I'm looking forward to work together with you (users and moderators alike) to make English Language Learners a better place for all.

Thanks to @AIQ and @Daniil for stepping up; without you, the election wouldn't have been possible. Good luck next time, wherever that may be (perhaps [elsewhere in the network](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54355450)).

Congratulations to @EddieKal, I'm happy to help you getting familiar with the moderator tools, though I'm sure the current team will be doing this as well (just as they will make me familiar with the specifics of moderating ELL; every community has its own unique character).

Comment: Thank you! Also big shout-out to all. Looking forward to it!

Comment: Look at your shiny new diamonds @EddieKal and Glorfindel :) So stylish! I know you two are going to do great.

Comment: @ColleenV I am still learning to adjust to it. It's going to take longer than I expected. I think my first mod action won't happen until I get myself acclimated to the new role.

Comment: @Glorifindel, congrats!!!!